# Ask repeatly another question if solved one

Tags: discussion, support

I answer to one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436897/customized-ul-with-symbol-or-picture/30436937?noredirect=1#comment48959248_30436937) the OP will say thanks for answer and ask again another question in comment related to it.

OP need some changes So, Make changes and Edit my answer and update to OP for my changes So, They again ask for another changes in comment. This think happen 3-4 times.

Upto now they didn't accepted any of the answer. They did same thing with answer people also on same question.

What will i have to do? I should give answer to them?  Or i need to ignore them.

Currently i close vote that question as a too broad. Is it ok?

Comment: Search for the term "help vampire".

Comment: Required reading: [Exit strategies for chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) on Meta.SE.

Comment: You are not obliged to keep providing help of any kind. Comments aren't meant for discussions nor further help. Just tell the user to open a new question if needed and be done with it.

Comment: How did that donut get so much rep? I'd vote to close and walk away in your place.

Comment: Its sometimes seems that there is a subversive competition going on between some students to see who can con the most unpaid work out of SO contributors.  The winner gets upvotes from the losers:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone is asking follow up questions in the comments just walk away. Comments are not the place for questions and answers - if nothing else the formatting options are limited.

If someone is changing their question then either rollback (just the once) or flag it for moderator attention if they are repeat offenders.